# Why TimeoutException does not need to be caught when executing AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, exception, timeoutexception

I am quite new to Java and Android development. I looked at the code of `AsyncTask`, and saw the class throws 3 Exceptions:

- `InterruptedException`
- `ExecutionException`
- `TimeoutException`​

When I run the execute method on an `AsyncTask` object, why is it that the compiler complains if I don't catch `InterruptedException` and `ExecutionException`, but does not complain about `TimeoutException`​?

More generally, how do we know which exceptions need to be caught? (Of course I look at the compiler errors and write the missing catch blocks, but I'd like to understand the principal behind it).

Thank you very much!

```
Example code:
public void test() {
    AsyncTask at = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    Object o;
    try {
        o = at.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Edit: I checked that `TimeoutException` is a checked exception (which should be caught). However @NicolasFilotto already answered my question. Thank you all.

Comment: I checked that TimeoutException is a checked exception. However @NicolasFilotto already answered my question. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`get()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()) method only throws `InterruptedException`, `ExecutionException` and `CancellationException` that is why you don't need to catch `TimeoutException` in your case, only the method [`get(long timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit unit)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) throws the 3 exceptions listed above and `CancellationException` which is the counterpart of `get()` but with a timeout.

**NB:** `CancellationException` is an unchecked exception so it doesn't need to be caught.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @NicolasFilotto it was helpful of you :)